# How to find a words in html file

Tags: bash

I need an script to find a word for example "config" from my html file and display five characters after that, it can be sed or awk or xpath, as long as it working.

this is mine but its not working:

```
sed -nE '/config/s/.*config(.{,5}).*>/\1/p' Lab-console.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-o` option of `grep` if available:

```
grep -oE 'config.{5}' Lab-console.html
```

If you want lines where there are less then five characters after `config`, too, just change it to

```
config.{,5}
```

Comment: ThANKS for your reply choroba, should i install grep first? can u please give me a example with sed command too?

Comment: @user3409828: `grep`  should be already installed. Just check it supports `-o`.

Comment: Its working thanks for your help, just one question, when I try it with normal txt file it gives me the output(the word "config" and 5 characters after that) but when i try it with html file there is no output, i guess its because of .html and it trying to open the file, any thought?

Comment: Html files are text files, too. Just check that the word `config` is really there (try View Source in your browser). Also, the file might be UTF-16 etc.